# ActionFilter compatible with both Mvc and WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I created an ASP .NET **WebApi** application that has a web service part which I wrote myself, and a web site part that came by default after creating the project and which provides a dynamically generated documentation for the web service part.

I created a whitelist of domain names and IP addresses allowed to access both the web service and web site parts of the application. For that purpose, I wrote an action filter responsible for returning an HTTP code 403 to non-whitelisted visitors.

Apparently, Mvc and WebAPI being two different frameworks, I cannot reuse my filter for both parts of my application, the one expecting a WebAPI action filter and the other excepting an Mvc action filter.

So my question is: is there a way to make a filter compatible with both, or will I end up being force to factor my code into some shared class and call if from two different action filter classes?

Comment: What version of .NET is this? Also, it would be much better to show an example of the code you are running here.

Comment: I'm not really sure about the version. It's the one that comes when creating a new projet in VS2022. It's the regular ASP .NET, not the Core one.

Comment: If your "regular ASP.NET" is what people usually refer to as ASP.NET 4.x, then the answer is no way. ASP.NET Core was created to unify the API, so unless you upgrade you are stuck there.